# Bootstrap WYSIWYG toolbar buttons relocation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I just got this bootstrap WYSIWYG Editor from github

http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

and the only line of code to display the form is this:

and the Js
$('.textarea').wysihtml5();

[image: wysiwyg]

How can i show the toolbars [bold, underline, italics etc.] below the form.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited code in the CSS

```
 ul.wysihtml5-toolbar {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 5px;
```

}